# Fedora 15 locale not getting set correctly

Tags: bash, locale, fedora

I have a C program (DHCPD) running on Fedora 15; it uses the `on commit` statement (which in turn uses the `exec` command) to call a script. The `$LANG` variable of the script is always set to `en_US.UTF-8` when all locale files (e.g. i18n) are set to `en_GB.utf8`.

Interestingly, when the script is run from a shell prompt, the `$LANG` variable is set to `en_GB.utf8` - how do I get it to use `en_GB.utf8` when called from the DHCPD program???

Comment: Either dhcpd is resetting the environment, or the environment passed to dhcpd is set that way.

Comment: I don't understand he comment ' or the environment passed to dhcpd is set that way' - if the environment was being passed then surely it should use the environment files?

Comment: Why do you think the environment files would be used when starting a daemon? Probably it skips those for performance.

Comment: in that case where is it getting its locale settings from?

Answer (score 1):

Well the first thing to do is to check `/etc/sysconfig/i18n` and see what `LANG` is set to.

Fedora 15 will be using `systemd` to start services like `dhcpd` and it will ignore the users environment and give each daemon that it starts a clean environment. It does take settings from `/etc/sysconfig/i18n` though so daemons should run with the settings specified there.

If that seems to be correct that look at `/proc/NNN/environ` where NNN is the PID of your dhcpd process to see what `LANG` is set to. Note that this file is the raw environment so has a binary nul between each string.

If that is what you expect then the most likely answer is that `dhcpd` is deliberately cleaning the environment before invoking scripts specified in it's configuration file.

Comment: Hi; thanks for that, the environ file only has an entry for PATH. If dhcpd is cleaning the environment then surely it must be using the system files to reset it?

Comment: In that case you should add `LANG="en_GB.utf8"` to it, or install `system-config-language` and run it, which will set it for you.

Comment: yep I did both of them - added en_GB.utf8 to i18n and ran the system-config-language program - still comes out as en_US.UTF-8!!!

Comment: hold on; LANG is being set in the environ file - i missed it - sorry - checking now.....

Comment: Sorry I misread your first comment and thought you mean the i18n file. Are you sure the environ file only has one entry - maybe it is just being truncated at the first nul? Try looking at it in vi...

Comment: the environ file has a few settings including $PATH and $LANG but i cannot edit the file and, every time i reboot, dhcpd has a different process id so editing the file makes no sense - where is the environ file getting its settings from?

Comment: And what is LANG's value in the /proc/NNN/environ pseudo file? These settings stem from the parent process; you could look for its ID with `ps -fCdhcpd` and inspect /proc/_PPID_/environ.